# Frustum position, origin and culling

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am writing a simple program that uses perspective projection and I have a bunch of objects drawn in my scene. For perspective projection I am using the following code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(eyePosX, eyePosY, eyePosZ, centerPosX, centerPosY, centerPosZ, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glFrustum(frustumLeft,frustumRight,frustumBottom,frustumTop,frustumNear,frustumFar);
```

When I have an object drawn with a certain offset on the X axis that does not inside into the frustum, the object is stil drawn, but is elongated and not culled by the frustum.
What are the coordinates of the 8 points in the XYZ space with respect to eyePosX/Y/Z and frustumLeft/Right/Bottom/Top/Near/Far? 
How can I tell OpenGL to perform the culling of the objects that are not inside the frustum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For perspective projection I am using the following code:

There are two possibilities. The first is that you really didn't mean to do what this code does. The second is that you *did* mean it, but don't fully understand what you've done.

Let's cover the first one now. The look-at matrix should never go *inside* the `GL_PROJECTION` matrix. Also, the look-at matrix always comes *after* the projection matrix. These should always be true *unless* you're doing something special.

Which leads to the second. If you really intend to rotate and offset the post-projective space, then you cannot expect geometry to be culled against the frustum. Why?

Because OpenGL doesn't do frustum culling. It culls against whatever post-T&L vertex positions you provide. If you rotate the view outside of the frustum, then that's what gets drawn. OpenGL doesn't draw what isn't visible; if you change the view post-projection so that things that wouldn't have been visible are visible now, then you've changed what is and is not visible.

Comment: I am a bit new to OpenGL and this perspective stuff is pretty confusing: the glFrustum needs 6 parameters for defining the 6 planes of the frustum, but which are the coordinates of the origin (the peak of the pyramid) and how can I specify those coordinates (I thought that glLook at function defines the origin)? And why does it not go in the GL_PROJECTION matrix?